# How to fix copy relation in array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

i want to do this:

i have a 2d array, i want to check every a[i][j],and put the result in some array with 0,1

this the relation between a graph node,but i got wrong answer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a[3][3]={{0,5,-1},{5,0,3},{-1,3,0}};
int k=0;
int b[6]={0};
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
   {
       cout<<a[i][j]<<"  ";
       if(a[i][j]==0 or a[i][j]==-1)
       {
           b[k]==0;
           k++;
       }
       else
       {
           b[k]==1;
           k++;
       }
   }
   cout<<endl;

}

for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    cout<<b[i]<<" ";
}

}
```

so how can i fix that array b to save correct answers,i mean if the nodes have relation put 1 and if the dont have relation (-1) or have no weight (0) put 0 in array b

Comment: What do you expect to be in the vector b, if it is correctly populated?  Why is the length of b only 6 elements?

Comment: @NicholasM becaus ewith have only 6 relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appear that you came from other language

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a[3][3] = {{0, 5, -1}, {5, 0, 3}, {-1, 3, 0}};
  int k = 0;
  int b[9] = {0}; // look here 9 elements
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      cout << a[i][j] << "  ";
      if (a[i][j] == 0 || a[i][j] == -1) { // look here change or by ||
        b[k] = 0; // look here you were testing for value 0 and doing nothing with the result (not assigning value)
        k++;
      } else {
        b[k] = 1; // look here same that before.
        k++;
      }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    cout << b[i] << " ";
  }
}
```

According with your problem statement, you are setting values to **b** where ever there is or not a relation (1 in one case and 0 in the other, because of that, size 9 of **b** is needed)

Answer (score 0):

3 x 3 = 9, `b` should hold 9 elements. By writing to array offsets that do not exist such as `b[6]`, `b[7]` and `b[8]` you will be invoking undefined behaviour possibly overwriting other stack variables such as `i` and `j` causing issues.

Also:

```
b[k]==0;
b[k]==1;
```

The operator `==` performs comparison, you are not assigning values to `b[k]`. The value assignment operator is `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Change these

```
b[k]==0;
b[k]==1;
```

to :

```
b[k]=0;
b[k]=1;
```

You must know the difference .!

Answer (score 0):

**in it exist 3 problem**
1.The assignment operator is '=',not '=='
2.b must has 9(3*3) element
3.or assignment is '||' not 'or'